# Why do I get a syntax error for 2e + 2?

Tags: javascript

I read a style guide that said to put spaces around operators like `+`. But when I try to write a number in exponent notation, I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Why?

Here's what I typed into the Chrome console:

```
a = 2e + 2;a ++
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here's snippet:

```js
a = 2e + 2;a ++;
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces here `2e + 2;` and `a ++`?

Comment: `a = 2e + 2;a ++` here `2e` is a string and you are trying to concat so that it will error. string should be in a quotes

Comment: You can't have spaces after `e`, for the same reason you can't have spaces between digits of a number. The number has to be one token.

Comment: @PankajMakwana: No, `2e` in the above is not a string. It's a syntax error. (Well, no, the space after it is...)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I don't know it's a typo. I read a  js-style-guide which says you should put space before and after "+". I checked it again after I read your comment and realized that I mistakely understood the guide. I vote for you because you have the most useful answer for my question. Thanks.

Comment: @paige: That's a very good point. And this question may well be useful to others in the future who make the same mistake for the same reason. I've retracted my close vote, and taken the liberty of editing the question to try to make it easier for people to find.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder No problem !  I've added the snippet. By the way, in this case, why I don't get back a error message which says "a is not defined"?

Comment: @paige: Because of [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  Thanks:-)

Answer (score 2):

A number has to be a single token, you can't put spaces in it. So you have to write:

```
2e+2
```

`2e` by itself is not valid syntax for any data type, so you get an error.

Regarding your comment on the question:

> I read a js-style-guide which says you should put space before and after "+"

That's good advice when you're using `+` as an operator (addition or string concatenation). But in `2e+2`, `+` isn't an operator, it's part of the number literal.

Answer (score 0):

The representation is wrong because there mustn't be spaces before and after `e`
it should be `var a = 2e+2; a++;`